# Multiple correlations using table.Correlation of PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, correlation, performanceanalytics

I am trying to run multiple correlations from a data set that is not a time series. I found the package `PerformanceAnalytics` the best output. However, I am consistently returning an error

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]    
table.Correlation(my_data[,1], my_data[,2:6])
        Error in checkData(Rb) : 
      The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'
```

However, the package documentation state the I can use a vector, matrix, data.frame and others formats. Actually, I can even run a correlation, but using the function `chart.Correlation`

`chart.Correlation(my_data, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)`

Does anyone know how to fix this?